# cartier duality is a contravariant equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can I get a reference for the statement that Cartier duality gives a contravariant equivalence from the category of finite etale group schemes to itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 2.4 of Waterhouse's *Introduction to Affine Group Schemes* (he doesn't number theorems for some reason). You forgot "commutative."

Comment: I think that it's probably easier to just check it over $k^\text{sep}$ and make sure that the obvious isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\vee\vee}\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ preserves Galois action and that the obvious map isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})\to \text{Hom}((\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\vee,(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\vee)$ sends Gal-equivariant things to Gal equivariant things. Of course, if you're not working over $\text{Spec}(k)$ but just some connected $T$ just replace Gal with the fundamental group.